# Divide Python list into multiple lists based on element condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I take a python list and divide it into multiple lists based on element conditions?

```
myList = ['Georgia', 12344, 52353, 'Alabama', 352947, 394567, 123437, 'Florida', 992344, 788345]




for each in myList:
  do stuff
```

result:

```
list1 = ['Georgia', 12344, 52353,]
list2 = ['Alabama', 352947, 394567, 123437]
list3 = ['Florida', 992344, 788345]
```

Comment: `doStuff`... apparently you forgot to try that command yourself

Comment: Looking at your previous question, it seems you're familiar with python. What, exactly, is the sticking point here? You ain't doing it with a list comprehension because you want 3 lists at the end of it

Comment: @Barmar that's not a dupe. It's clear they want to split on string vs int

Comment: Oops didn't notice that the second one was longer.

Comment: Don't try to create dynamic variables. You should create a list of lists. You can probably do this with `itertools.groupby()`

Comment: The linked post does not answer this question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question - the sublists are not of equal length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isinstance` to check if it's a string or int. Start a new sublist or append to the sublist depending on condition.

```
newlists = []

for item in myList:
    if isinstance(item, str):
        new_sublist = [item]
        newlists.append(new_sublist)
    else:
        new_sublist.append(item)
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this should have been more obvious to me. Maybe I've just been looking at code for too long.